# The number of ways to buy 6 bagels if there are 10 types

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Problem:
A person goes into a bagel store that sells $10$ different types of bagels. He is
planning on buying $6$ bagels. How many ways can he purchase $6$ bagels?

Note: He can buy more than one of the same type of bagel.

Answer:
Let $c$ be the count we seek. The number of ways to select $n$ objects from a
set of $m$ variables is
$$ { {n+m-1} \choose {m-1}} $$
assuming you can select the same type more than once.
\begin{align*}
m &= 10 \\
n &= 6 \\
c &= { {6+10-1} \choose {10-1}} = { {15} \choose {9}} \\
c &= \dfrac{ 15(14)(13)(12)(11)(10) } { 6(5)(4)(3)(2)} \\
c &= \dfrac{ 15(14)(13)(11)(10) } { 5(4)(3)} \\
c &= \dfrac{ 15(14)(13)(11) } { 2(3)} = 5(7)(13)(11) \\
c &= 5005 \\
\end{align*}
Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes it is absolutely correct

Comment: @MathLover If you posted your comment as an answer, I could accept the answer and then close the question.